# Efficiently adding info to a list. Linq Union?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, comparator

I have some data which is queried from a database, but if there are no records for a particular financial year, it does not get returned in my list. I need all financial years returned, but the actual information (GrossEx, GST, GrossInc) should all be null.

```
public class FinancialData
{
    public string FinancialYear { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public decimal? GrossEx { get; set; }
    public decimal? GST { get; set; }
    public decimal? GrossInc { get; set; }
}
```

How do I efficiently add FinancialYears, from 2004 to 2015 (with Gross, GST and GrossInc being null), to my list if they do not exist?

```
List<FinancialData> financialDataBucket = new List<FinancialData>();

FinancialData entry1 = new FinancialData { FinancialYear = "2012 - 2013", GrossEx = 1, GrossInc = 1, GST = 1 };
FinancialData entry2 = new FinancialData { FinancialYear = "2013 - 2014", GrossEx = 1, GrossInc = 1, GST = 1 };

financialDataBucket.Add(entry1);
financialDataBucket.Add(entry2);
```

I've tried doing a Union with a linq comparer, but for some reason it didn't work, and I can't figure out why? Is this the best way to solve my problem?

```
var merged = allFinancialYearsData.Union(financialDataBucket, new EqComparer());

public class EqComparer : IEqualityComparer<FinancialData>
{
    public bool Equals( FinancialData x, FinancialData y )
    {
        return x.FinancialYear == y.FinancialYear;
    }

    public int GetHashCode( FinancialData obj )
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode ();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

So, I'm thinking about either creating 10 different financial year objects and adding them to a list, OR

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year + (DateTime.Now.Month < 7 ? 0 : 1);
var earliestYear = 2005;

for (int i = earliestYear; i <= currentYear; i++) {
    //Instantiate FinancialData here.....
   financialDataItem.FinancialYear = (i-1) + " - " + i
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Mmh... what's "faewfeawfewa" in your GetHashCode implementation ? Anyway, returing obj.GetHashCode means that you are comparing object references instead of values...

Comment: Show us how you create allFinancialYearsData.

Comment: fawefeawfewa probably means FinancialData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform a group join. In code snippet below, allRecords create dummy FinancialData for "2005 - 2006" to "2014 - 2015".

```
var allRecords = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new FinancialData { FinancialYear = string.Format("{0} - {1}", 2005 + x, 2005 + x + 1) });
var myRecords = new[] { new FinancialData { FinancialYear = "2012 - 2013", GrossEx = 1, GrossInc = 1, GST = 1 }, new FinancialData { FinancialYear = "2013 - 2014", GrossEx = 1, GrossInc = 1, GST = 1 } };
var result = allRecords.GroupJoin(myRecords
                , x => x.FinancialYear, y => y.FinancialYear, (x, y) => y.FirstOrDefault(u => u.FinancialYear == x.FinancialYear) ?? x);
```